# Uploading files ang getting it in the action's controller

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, razor

I have an application for uploading files and i made this view:

```
@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Upload a projet";
}

<section id="logout">  
        @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
            @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
            <a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Akeo")" >Se déconnecter</a>
        }
 </section>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Akeo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype = "multipart/form-data" }))
{
    <input type="file" name="dossier" />
   <br />
 <input type="submit" value="OK" />
 }
```

the action `Uploading_validation`

```
 [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Uploading_validation()
    {
        HttpPostedFileBase fileurl = null; 

        foreach (string file in Request.Files)
        {
             fileurl = Request.Files[file];
        }

        // Verify that the user selected a file
        if (fileurl != null && fileurl.ContentLength > 0)
        {
            // extract only the fielname
            var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
            // store the file inside ~/App_Data/uploads folder
            var path = @"C\Inetpub\wwwroot\"+fileName;
            fileurl.SaveAs(path);
        }
        // redirect back to the index action to show the form once again
        return RedirectToAction("Index");
    }
```

the problem that even i select a file the parameter `file` is always empty!!

What is the cause of this? how can i modify the code to fix this error?

Comment: `HttpPostedFileBase` instances. Once again, notice that the argument name **matches the name of the file inputs**. check [this link](http://lesson8.blogspot.in/2013/05/how-to-create-and-editorfor-fileupload.html)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

rename the name of input type to file and see if it works like this

```
@{
ViewBag.Title = "Upload a projet";
}

<section id="logout">  
    @using (Html.BeginForm("LogOff", "Account", FormMethod.Post, new { id = "logoutForm" })) {
        @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
        <a href="@Url.Action("Logout", "Akeo")" >Se déconnecter</a>
    }
</section>


@using (Html.BeginForm("Uploading_validation", "Akeo", FormMethod.Post, new { enctype =     "multipart/form-data" }))
{
<input type="file" name="file" />
<br />
<input type="submit" value="OK" />
}
```

Comment: please see my edit the problem now is i need an absolute path not inside the server

Comment: you have to give virtual path of the folder and not the physical path, hence enter Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(""), fileName); if you want to upload it to the root else enter the name of the folder in it as Path.Combine(Server.MapPath("upload"), fileName);

Answer (score 1):

try to rename parameter in action`public ActionResult Uploading_validation(HttpPostedFileBase dossier)`

Comment: i change my code to ` [HttpPost]
 public ActionResult Uploading_validation()
  {
  HttpPostedFileBase fileurl = null; 

   foreach (string file in Request.Files)
            {
                 fileurl = Request.Files[file];
            }
if (fileurl != null && fileurl.ContentLength > 0)
{ var fileName = Path.GetFileName(fileurl.FileName);
  var path = Path.Combine(Server.MapPath(@"C:\Inetpub\wwwroot\"), fileName);
                fileurl.SaveAs(path);
  }
 return RedirectToAction("Index");
}`  but the new  error is in the path (it needs a virtual path not a physical one). what is this means?

Comment: i dont know why u have the error in the path. Usualy im using the AppDomain.CurrentDomain.BaseDirectory +"/mypathtosave"; and it works for me, but i dont know is it the right way:)